# Looping grouping by ul list

Tags: php

i have in a table of my database 100 records of locations, and i need for example divide in 4 columns with ul list where each ul/columns have 25 records, but im not quite getting it working, here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM districts";
$consulta = mysql_query($sql);
$beginTag = '
    <div class="four columns">
        <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
        <ul class="footer-links">';

$endTag = '</ul></div>';
$html = '';

$counter = 4;
if ($counter >= 4) {
    echo $beginTag;
}

while ($mostrar = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    $counter++;
    $town = $mostrar['name_en'];                

    echo '<li><a href="#"><strong>'.$town.'</strong> Jobs</a></li>';            

    $counter = 0;

}

if ($counter >= 4) {
    echo $endTag;
}
```

Comment: You should be more specific in your description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so you should use `mysqli_*` or PDO. 
The following code will result in four `ul` of `25` `li`. Using CSS you can align these `ul`'s in four columns.
Otherwise you could have 25 `ul` with 4 `li` in each one to achieve the same effect.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('your_server', 'your_username', 'your_password', 'your_database');
if (!$connection) {
    echo mysqli_connect_errno();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM districts";
$consulta = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$beginTag = '
    <div class="four columns">
        <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
        <ul class="footer-links">';

$i = 0;

while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array ($consulta)) {
    $town = $mostrar['name_en'];                
    if ($i % 25 == 0) {
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    }
    echo '<li><a href="#"><strong>'.$town.'</strong> Jobs</a></li>';
    $i++;
}

echo '</ul></div>';
```

Comment: its not workin, is showing each 25 in one ul, but each ul have to have one "<div class="four columns">
        <h4>&nbsp;</h4>" wrapped up.

Comment: Please edit your question explaining better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code: the counter is reset on every loop so never reaches your maximum and your `$beginTag` and `$endTag` are not output in the loop.

You can calculate the number of rows per column by getting the row count from the db query so that the code still works if the number of rows changes in future.

You should also use `mysqli` since the MySQL extension has been deprecated for years and is about to be dropped in the upcoming PHP7 release.

```
// assumes your mysqli_connect on $con
$sql = "SELECT * FROM districts";
$consulta = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$beginTag = '
    <div class="four columns">
        <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
        <ul class="footer-links">';
$endTag = '</ul></div>';
$html = '';
// calculate the max rows per column
$cols = 4;
$max = ceil(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) / $cols);
$counter = 0;
while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
  // check for first row to output the beginTag
  if ($counter == 0) {
    echo $beginTag;
  }
  $town = $mostrar['name_en'];
  echo '<li><a href="#"><strong>'.$town.'</strong> Jobs</a></li>';            
  $counter++;
  // check for max per column
  if ($counter >= $max) {
    echo $endTag;
    // reset the counter
    $counter = 0;
  }
}
```